# Bootstrap navbar button will not collapse when included as a header file with JQuery

Tags: jquery, html, css, navbar

I am using CDN bootstrap navbar with the collapsible button as a header for all pages on a website that I am developing. The code is below. When this code is part of an HTML file, everything works perfectly fine.

```
<nav class="navbar navbar-default navbar-fixed-top">
    <div class="container-fluid">
        <!-- Brand and toggle get grouped for better mobile display -->
        <div class="navbar-header">
            <a class="navbar-brand" href="http://<webaddress>/working/home.html">
                <img class="logo-main" src="images/logo.png">
            </a>
            <a class="navbar-brand" href="http://<webaddress>.com/working/home.html">
                <img class="name-main" src="images/name.png">
            </a>
            <button type="button" class="navbar-toggle collapsed" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#navbar-collapse-button" aria-expanded="false">
                <span class="icon-bar"></span>
                <span class="icon-bar"></span>
                <span class="icon-bar"></span>
            </button>                

        </div><!-- /.navbar-header -->

        <!-- Collect the nav links, forms, and other content for toggling -->
        <div class="collapse navbar-collapse" id="navbar-collapse-button">
            <ul class="nav navbar-nav navbar-right">
                <li class="active"><a href="#">Home </a></li>
                <li><a href="http://<webaddress>/dining">Dining</a></li>
                <li><a href="http://<webaddress>/event-activities">Events & Activities</a></li>
                <li><a href="http://<webaddress>/private-party">Private Party</a></li>
                <li><a href="http://<webaddress>/gallery">Gallery</a></li>
                <li><a href="http://<webaddress>/media-contact">Media & Contact</a></li>
            </ul>
        </div><!-- /.navbar-collapse -->
    </div><!-- /.container-fluid -->
</nav>
```

Since this code appears on many webpages on the top, I created a `header.html` file with all jQuery, Bootstrap and CSS references and copied the above code to `header.html`, then I added these lines in each of the webpages:

```
<head>
<script> 
    $(function(){
        $("#header").load("header.html"); 
        $("#footer").load("footer.html"); 
    });
</script> 
</head>

<body>

<div id="header"></div>
```

With the identical code loaded by Jquery as a header, everything works just the same except for the button. After being expanded, clicking it again would not collapse it. All other functions, like responsive functions, work the same. However, when this same code is part of the individual webpages, the button works fine.
What is wrong with the code and how do I fix it?
Thanks.

Comment: Do you have any console errors?

Comment: You use jQuery notation _before_ jQuery has loaded?

Comment: Could you provide full html layout. Where you placed bootstrap js script ?

Comment: Thanks for the responses. To answer the questions: 1. There is no console error. 2. JQuery, Bootstrap and CSS were all loaded before, I just did not include them in the post above but they are in the correct order. In fact, when the header file is run by itself, it works perfectly. Also, like I mentioned, all other script functions (like responsive) are okay, including the button expanding the menu. The only thing that does not work is collapsing the menu back. The collapsing function breaks when the header.html file is loaded into the other pages. 3. I used CDN.

Comment: One new observation. In Chrome or Firefox, I couldn't tell what's going on because the button just would not collapse. However, in Safari, every click after the initial expanding re-animates the expansion over and over again as if it does not know that the menu has already been expanded. I am new to JQuery/Javascript but is it possible that when JQuery loads a file, it has restrictions in passing active parameters? In this case, after the button expands the menu, it cannot update the state variable to toggle back to collapse on the next click.